# How to Add Toggle Switch Button in Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am trying to add a custom Button in Full Calendar but I want a Switch Button as shown below instead of a simple click button , How can I achieve this?

[image]

Code Snippet :

```
customButtons: {
     availableSlotsToggleBtn: {
         text: 'Available Slots',
            change: () => {
                 this.updateCalendar();
            }
          }
      },
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'availableSlotsToggleBtn,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code [here](http://react.new/)?

Comment: Typically these types of things are actually checkboxes, but made to LOOK LIKE "buttons". See here for example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/#switches - you can of course add handlers so that they do what you want

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons describes what you can do with custom buttons in fullCalendar. It's quite limited. If you need something more complex, you'll likely have to create the buttons yourself and place them outside the calendar header, so you have full control over them.

Comment: P.S. If you're interested in getting more flexibility in this feature for the future, please make a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to ask for it to be enhanced. And of course since it's an open-source project, you could even [contribute the necessary code yourself](https://fullcalendar.io/contributing)